# Python: What structure of data is stockstats expecting?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
                       T         L         H         O         C           BV
0    2015-08-14T00:00:00  0.006667  0.080000  0.006900  0.007000    29.545465
1    2015-08-15T00:00:00  0.005950  0.007240  0.006740  0.006954    20.274633
2    2015-08-16T00:00:00  0.004120  0.006900  0.006501  0.006051    47.971549
3    2015-08-17T00:00:00  0.004655  0.006139  0.006139  0.004798    30.391738
```

It's created from a json:

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

Now I try to use [stockstats](https://github.com/jealous/stockstats) to calculate the MACD.
I tried (following [this blog](https://romanorac.github.io/cryptocurrency/analysis/2017/12/17/cryptocurrency-analysis-with-python-part1.html) a bit):

```
df = StockDataFrame.retype(df)
df['macd'] = df.get('macd')
```

But I get the following error:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'close'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

- Do I need to update `2015-08-14T00:00:00` to `2015-08-14`?
- What type of columns (amount/names) is stockstats expecting? I can not find it anywhere?
- Do I have to call my columns 'open', 'close', ...?

Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like you need to change the column names. `stockstats()` expects the closing price to be named `close`, your dataframe calls it `C`.

Comment: See the files in the `test_data` directory for examples of the expected input format.